# Repository vs Services: Where do the queries that return data from "joins" between models go?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to better understand the use of Model, Repository, and Service patterns.

- If we only put basic operations like creating, updating, deleting,
  and finding an entity in the Model;
- If we put queries that operate on the whole entity in the repository,
  like finding entities of this model;
- If we put queries that work with API orchestration, data that is
  returned from the repository in the Service.

Where do the queries that return data from "joins" between models go?

Answer (score 0):

Model, Repository, and Service are hihly depend on what architecture you are using.

For instance, let's consdier [traditional "N-layer" architecture application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#traditional-n-layer-architecture-applications):

Business Classes and Repositories solve different problems, and therefore are different Concerns in the application. As such, they need to be in separate classes.

Business Classes and Repositories have different goals, and therefore are various Concerns in the application. As  a consequence, they need to be in separate classes.

A Repository's main purpose is to provide a layer of abstraction between persistence and your code. Switching database vendors, or even storage mediums (database, flat file, web service, etc) shouldn't matter outside of your Repository classes.

The purpose of a Business Class is to enforce business logic.

You can read more here in this very [thorough and nice answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-accurate-is-business-logic-should-be-in-a-service-not-in-a-model).